# Hover on input to sibling item does not work

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a basic nav-bar. This nav bar contains a "search" button.

My goal is to make a hover in the search button that makes appear an input (and moves the button to the left) for the user to search anything he wants.

The thing is: I need to make the search button move to the left when I hover the input too, and I'm not figuring it out.

And as you see with that code, the item bugs.

Here's the code:

```css
/*----------NAV BAR----------*/
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.nav-backgc {
    height: 140px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    transition: 0.4s;
    z-index: 9;
    backdrop-filter: blur(1rem);
    background-color: #DAA520;
}

.container-nav {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: inherit 9;
}

.logonav {
    max-width: 65px;
    padding: 10px 0px 2px 0px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: -5px;
    display: none;
}

.logo {
    max-width: 65px;
    padding: 10px 0px 2px 0px;
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.navbar ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.navbar li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 25px;
    position: relative;
}

.navcarrito span {
    display: none;
}

.navbar a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar a {
    color: #fff;
}

.barra {
    margin-top: 27px;
}

hr {
    opacity: 20%
}

.navcarrito.login-carrito {
    display: none;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.navcarrito {
    display: flex;
    float: right;
    position: fixed;
    right: 20%;
    margin-top: -35px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.navlogin {
    float: right;
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    right: 1.5%;
    margin-top: -35px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.navlogin {
    float: right;
    position: fixed;
    right: 1.5%;
    margin-top: -35px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.nav-arriba {
    padding-top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav-arriba a {
    text-decoration: none;

}

.nav-arriba ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-arriba li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 25px;
    position: relative;
}

.search {
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.search:hover {
    margin-right: 100px;
}

.searchBuscador {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

input:focus:hover {
    margin-right: 100px;
}

.search:hover~.searchBuscador {
    display: inline-block;
}

/* ==========================================================================
DROPDOWN MENU
========================================================================== */
.dropdownMenu {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 7px;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px rgba(163, 163, 163, 0.295);
}

.dropdownBoton:hover>.dropdownMenu {
    display: flex;
}

.dropdownMenu a {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 35%;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-block-start: 0.5em;
    height: 100px;
}

.dropdownMenu a h3 {
    margin-block-start: 16px;
    margin-block-end: -9.5px;
}

/* ==========================================================================
RESOLUCION 1200-1600
========================================================================== */
@media (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1600px) {
    .navlogin li a {
        display: none;
    }

    .navcarrito span {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .navcarrito {
        right: 6%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1300px) {
    .navcarrito li {
        margin: 0px 15px;
    }
}

/*****RESOLUCION 1024*****/
@media (min-width:1024px) {}

/*****RESOLUCION 768*****/
@media (min-width:768px) {}

/*****RESOLUCION 480*****/
@media (min-width:480px) {}

/*****RESOLUCION 320*****/
@media (min-width:320px) {}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/stylesheets/nav.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8431526c8f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<header>
    <div id="navbar" class="nav-backgc">
        <div class="container-nav">
            <div class="navbar">
                <center>
                    <a href="/"><img src="/images/logo2.png" alt="BierClub" class="logo"></a>
                    <ul id="navcarrito" class="navcarrito">
                        <li class="search"><a href="/productos"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="/productCart"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a></li>
                        <div class="searchBuscador">
                            <input type="text"></input>
                        </div>
                        <span>
                            <li class="login-carrito"><a href="/login"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></a></li>
                        </span>
                    </ul><strong>
                        <ul id="navlogin" class="navlogin">
                            <li><a href="/login"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Iniciar sesion</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </strong>
                    <hr><a href="/"><img src="/images/logo2.png" alt="BierClub" class="logonav" id="logonav"></a>
                    <nav>
                        <ul class="barra"><strong>
                                <li class="dropdownBoton"><a href="/productos">Productos</a>
                                    <div class="dropdownMenu">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <h3>Lupuladas</h3>
                                            <h6>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h6>
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <h3>No lupuladas</h3>
                                            <h6>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h6>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="/promociones">Promociones</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/promociones">Suscribete</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/envios">Envio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/quienes_somos">¿Quienes Somos?</a></li>
                        </ul></strong>
                    </nav>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: try to make navbar using Bootstrap

Comment: i have confused with your Code..

Comment: there are so many faults in your html document...

Comment: I'm trying to learn, that's why I don't use bootstrap, thanks for the tip though

Comment: don't werry . you can get all parts templates from bootstrap officiel website

Comment: Here you can check - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:**
Onclick javascript statement added...

```js
function search(){
  document.getElementById("search-bar").style = "display:block;";
  document.getElementById("search-bar").focus() ;
}
```

```css
    /*----------NAV BAR----------*/
body{
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.nav-backgc{
  height:140px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.4s;
  z-index: 9;
  backdrop-filter: blur(1rem);
  background-color: #DAA520;
}

.container-nav{
  width : 80%;
  margin-left:10%;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:inherit 9;
}

.logonav{
  max-width: 65px;
  padding: 10px 0px 2px 0px;
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  margin-top: -5px;
  display:none;
}

.logo{
  max-width: 65px;
  padding: 10px 0px 2px 0px;
}

nav{
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.navbar ul{
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.navbar li{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 25px;
  position: relative;
}
.navcarrito span{
  display: none;
}
.navbar a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar a{
  color: #fff;
}

.barra{
  margin-top: 27px;
}

hr{
  opacity:20%
}
.navcarrito.login-carrito{
  display: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.navcarrito{
  display: flex;
  float:right;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20%;
  margin-top: -35px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.navlogin{
  float:right;
  display:flex;
  position:fixed;
  right: 1.5%;
  margin-top: -35px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.navlogin{
  float:right;
  position:fixed;
  right: 1.5%;
  margin-top: -35px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.nav-arriba{
  padding-top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav-arriba a{
  text-decoration: none;

}
.nav-arriba ul{
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.nav-arriba li{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 25px;
  position: relative;
}
.search{
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.search:hover{
 /* margin-right: 100px; */
}
.searchBuscador1{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
}
#search-bar{
  display:none;
}
input:focus:hover{
 /* margin-right: 100px;*/
}
.search:focus .searchBuscador{
/*  display: inline-block;*/
  display:block;
    
}
  /* ==========================================================================
   DROPDOWN MENU
   ========================================================================== */
.dropdownMenu{
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 7px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px rgba(163, 163, 163, 0.295);
}
.dropdownBoton:hover > .dropdownMenu{
  display:flex;
}
.dropdownMenu a{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 35%;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-block-start: 0.5em;
  height: 100px;
}
.dropdownMenu a h3{
  margin-block-start: 16px;
  margin-block-end: -9.5px;
}

  /* ==========================================================================
   RESOLUCION 1200-1600
   ========================================================================== */
@media (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1600px) {
  .navlogin li a{
    display:none;
  }
  .navcarrito span{
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .navcarrito{
    right: 6%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1300px) {
  .navcarrito li{
    margin: 0px 15px;
  }
}

/*****RESOLUCION 1024*****/
@media (min-width:1024px) {

}

/*****RESOLUCION 768*****/
@media (min-width:768px) {

}

/*****RESOLUCION 480*****/
@media (min-width:480px) {

}

/*****RESOLUCION 320*****/
@media (min-width:320px) {

}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>navbar</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="/images/faviconLogo.ico"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/speak.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/stylesheets/nav.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8431526c8f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<style>
  
/**Style Sheet - CSS **/

</style>
<body>
<header>
    <div id="navbar" class="nav-backgc">
    <div class ="container-nav">
        <div class ="navbar">
            <center>
                <a href="/"><img src="/images/logo2.png" alt="BierClub" class="logo"></a>
                <ul id ="navcarrito" class="navcarrito">
                    <li class="search"><a href="#"><i  class="fas fa-search" onclick="search()" ></i><!/a></li>
                  <div class="searchBuscador">
                        <input type="text" onblur="this.style='display:none;'"
                               id="search-bar"></input>
                  </div>
              <li><a href="/productCart"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a></li>
                    
                    <span><li class="login-carrito"><a href="/login"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></a></li></span>
                </ul><strong>
                <ul id ="navlogin" class="navlogin">
                    <li><a href="/login"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Iniciar sesion</a></li>
                </ul></strong>
                <hr><a href="/"><img src="/images/logo2.png" alt="BierClub" class="logonav" id="logonav"></a>
                <nav>
                <ul class="barra"><strong>
                    <li class="dropdownBoton"><a href="/productos">Productos</a>
                    <div class="dropdownMenu">
                        <a href="#">
                            <h3>Lupuladas</h3>
                            <h6>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h6>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#">
                            <h3>No lupuladas</h3>
                            <h6>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h6>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/promociones">Promociones</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/promociones">Suscribete</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/envios">Envio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/quienes_somos">¿Quienes Somos?</a></li>
                </ul></strong>
                </nav>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</header>

  <script>
/** Javascript **/
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: best user experience is Onclick. hover is not available for mobile devices.

Comment: Thanks guys! Onclick sounds much better. Will use that on my code

Comment: great! if the answer usful for you , give tik **✓** to the answer

Answer (score 0):

**Hover Effect..**

```css
    /*----------NAV BAR----------*/
body{
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.nav-backgc{
  height:140px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.4s;
  z-index: 9;
  backdrop-filter: blur(1rem);
  background-color: #DAA520;
}

.container-nav{
  width : 80%;
  margin-left:10%;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:inherit 9;
}

.logonav{
  max-width: 65px;
  padding: 10px 0px 2px 0px;
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  margin-top: -5px;
  display:none;
}

.logo{
  max-width: 65px;
  padding: 10px 0px 2px 0px;
}

nav{
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.navbar ul{
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.navbar li{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 25px;
  position: relative;
}
.navcarrito span{
  display: none;
}
.navbar a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar a{
  color: #fff;
}

.barra{
  margin-top: 27px;
}

hr{
  opacity:20%
}
.navcarrito.login-carrito{
  display: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.navcarrito{
  display: flex;
  float:right;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20%;
  margin-top: -35px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.navlogin{
  float:right;
  display:flex;
  position:fixed;
  right: 1.5%;
  margin-top: -35px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.navlogin{
  float:right;
  position:fixed;
  right: 1.5%;
  margin-top: -35px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.nav-arriba{
  padding-top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav-arriba a{
  text-decoration: none;

}
.nav-arriba ul{
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.nav-arriba li{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 25px;
  position: relative;
}
.search{
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.search:hover{
 /* margin-right: 100px; */
}
.searchBuscador{
  display:none;/*
  position:absolute;*/
}

input:focus{
 /* margin-right: 100px;*/
  display:block;
}
.search:hover ~ .searchBuscador{
/*  display: inline-block;*/
  display:block;
    
}
  /* ==========================================================================
   DROPDOWN MENU
   ========================================================================== */
.dropdownMenu{
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 7px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px rgba(163, 163, 163, 0.295);
}
.dropdownBoton:hover > .dropdownMenu{
  display:flex;
}
.dropdownMenu a{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 35%;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-block-start: 0.5em;
  height: 100px;
}
.dropdownMenu a h3{
  margin-block-start: 16px;
  margin-block-end: -9.5px;
}

  /* ==========================================================================
   RESOLUCION 1200-1600
   ========================================================================== */
@media (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1600px) {
  .navlogin li a{
    display:none;
  }
  .navcarrito span{
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .navcarrito{
    right: 6%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1300px) {
  .navcarrito li{
    margin: 0px 15px;
  }
}

/*****RESOLUCION 1024*****/
@media (min-width:1024px) {

}

/*****RESOLUCION 768*****/
@media (min-width:768px) {

}

/*****RESOLUCION 480*****/
@media (min-width:480px) {

}

/*****RESOLUCION 320*****/
@media (min-width:320px) {

}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>navbar</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="/images/faviconLogo.ico"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/speak.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/stylesheets/nav.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8431526c8f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
<header>
    <div id="navbar" class="nav-backgc">
    <div class ="container-nav">
        <div class ="navbar">
            <center>
                <a href="/"><img src="/images/logo2.png" alt="BierClub" class="logo"></a>
                <ul id ="navcarrito" class="navcarrito">
                    <li class="search"><a href="#"><i  class="fas fa-search"  ></i></a></li>
                  <div class="searchBuscador">
                        <input type="txt" >
                  </div>
              <li><a href="/productCart"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a></li>
                    
                    <span><li class="login-carrito"><a href="/login"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></a></li></span>
                </ul><strong>
                <ul id ="navlogin" class="navlogin">
                    <li><a href="/login"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Iniciar sesion</a></li>
                </ul></strong>
                <hr><a href="/"><img src="/images/logo2.png" alt="BierClub" class="logonav" id="logonav"></a>
                <nav>
                <ul class="barra"><strong>
                    <li class="dropdownBoton"><a href="/productos">Productos</a>
                    <div class="dropdownMenu">
                        <a href="#">
                            <h3>Lupuladas</h3>
                            <h6>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h6>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#">
                            <h3>No lupuladas</h3>
                            <h6>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h6>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/promociones">Promociones</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/promociones">Suscribete</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/envios">Envio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/quienes_somos">¿Quienes Somos?</a></li>
                </ul></strong>
                </nav>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</header>

  </body>
</html>
```